# Accessing unity container in view model class

Tags: wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

I have a shell which looks like toolbar and defines my main region (a wrap panel).  What I need to do is be able to add widgets to the shell and when a widget is clicked, a new window (view) is opened.  Below is what I have so far:

I created a module class which adds a view to the main region:

```
public class MyModule : IModule
{
  protected IUnityContainer Container { get; private set; }

  public MyModule(IUnityContainer container)
  {
    Container = container.CreateChildContainer();
  }

  public void Initialize()
  {
    var regionManager = Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
    MyModuleView myModuleView = new MyModuleView();
    regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].Add(myModuleView);
  }
}
```

Here is the content of MyModuleView:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
      <vm:MyModuleVM/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <Button Content="My Module" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Command="{Binding Path=LaunchCommand}">
    </Button>
  </Grid>
```

The view model, MyModuleVM:

```
  class MyModuleVM : ObservableObject
  {
    protected IUnityContainer Container { get; private set; }

    public MyModuleVM()
    {
    }

    RelayCommand _launchCommand;
    public ICommand LaunchCommand
    {
      get
      {
        if (_launchCommand == null)
        {
          _launchCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.LaunchTestView(),
              () => this.CanLaunchTestView());
        }
        return _launchCommand;
      }
    }

    private void LaunchTestView()
    {
      TestView view = new TestView();
      view.Title = "Test View";
      var regionManager = Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
      regionManager.Regions["MyWindowRegion"].Add(view);
    }

    private bool CanLaunchTestView()
    {
        return true;
    }
  }
```

So my plan was as follows:

- Create the class that implements
  IModule (MyModule) and have it load a
  view (MyModuleView) into the shell
  when initialized
- Create a view model for the module
  (MyModuleVM) and set it as the
  DataContext of the view displayed in
  the shell
- MyModuleVM contains a command that a
  button in MyModuleView binds to. 
  When the button is clicked the
  command is triggered
- Now, here is where I am stuck.  Using
  a WindowRegionAdapter (an adapter
  that helps to create views in
  separate windows) I wanted to create
  and display a new view.  As seen in
  MyModuleVM, LaunchTestView needs
  access to the container in order to
  add the view to a region.  How am I
  supposed to get to the container?

Besides my specific question about accessing the container, how is my overall strategy of adding "widgets" to a toolbar shell and launching
views when they are clicked?  Am I comlpetely off track here when it comes to MVVM with Prism?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the container injected through [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660875%28PandP.20%29.aspx) or [property injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660903%28PandP.20%29.aspx). To do that, the ViewModel instance must be [resolved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660934%28PandP.20%29.aspx) by the container, or the [BuildUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660934%28PandP.20%29.aspx) method should be called after it has been instantiated.

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Damian

Comment: Hey Damian.  My view model (which needs access to the container) is created through the xaml of the view.  Where would I even write the code to call container.Resolve or container.BuildUp?

Comment: In this case, you  can do it right after new MyModuleView() (i.e.: container.BuildUp(typeof(MyModuleVM), myModuleView.DataContext);), but in this kind of scenario, resolving teh RegionManager through the ServiceLocator might also be a good approach.

Comment: Hmm.  It looks like myModuleView.DataContext has not yet been created if I add the BuildUp right after MyModuleView myModuleView = new MyModuleView(). Maybe I am going about this wrong.  This seems like a simple task that I am making harder than it needs to be.  Is my approach to implement a toolbar with widget views that launch other views sound?  Do you know of any good resources discussing the ServiceLocator?

Comment: Some resources: http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/, Prism documentation and code, Prism forum questions at codeplex.

The common approach for "modular toolbars" is similar to the one you are following:
1) Load module.
2) Resolve V-VM pair.
3) Add V to toolbar region.
You seem to be having trouble with 2), so I would recommend taking a look at the Prism docs and code, as well as the Unity docs to understand the different ways the V-VM can be hooked together.