# How to resolve view using Mef container in a view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, mef

I have a view model containing a command where I want to add a new view to my shell's MainRegion (a tab control).

Seems to be that I need to use view injection rather than discovery which is fine.

i.e. from the prism documentation

```
IRegionManager regionManager = ...;
IRegion mainRegion = regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"];
NewView view = this.container.Resolve<NewView>();
mainRegion.Add(view);
```

How and where do I get a reference to the CompositionContainer in my view model in order to resolve NewView?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781205/accessing-unity-container-in-view-model-class) is effectively the same as yours.

Comment: Thanks. I see that the example you show is using the unity container. I'm using MEF. Just wondered when where I set the export on my container. Currently I'm not overriding the createcontainer / configurecontainer methods in my bootstrapper...

Comment: @obaylis - You would need to override CreateContainer, like shown [here](http://www.garrettgirod.com/?p=173) (at the end).

Comment: Thanks. I exported the CompositionContainer from my bootstrapper. Export needed to be static for it to work. Once that was done, I could import the CompositionContianer in my view model.

Answer (score 4):

The default MEF container exports itself by IServiceLocator. You may import service locator and region manager in your view model:

```
[Import]
private IRegionManager _regionManager;

[Import]
private IServiceLocator _serviceLocator;
```

And then use it for view injection:

```
public void ShowSomeView()
{
    IRegion region = _regionManager.Regions["Main"];
    var view = _serviceLocator.GetInstance(typeof(SomeView));
    region.Add(view, "SomeView");
    region.Activate(view);
}
```

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer.